# LARAVEL 8 - cannot pass data from controller to view -> undefined variable $test

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller, laravel-blade

hy everyone, i'm facing a problem that i saw lot of times here in SO but i'm not understanding why none of the solution people are giving are working for me..
i'm trying to print all the tables from my db in a dropdown menu ( so that i can choose one table and later modify it with a crud) using the web.php for the routes, the controller and the view.
in the example you'll see below i'm just trying to pass a variable, not the whole database

this is my controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class EditController extends Controller
{
   public function index(){
            $tables = 'test';
            return view('edit')->with('tables',$tables);
        }
    }
```

this is the  of edit.blade.php where it is the variable

```
<div class="card-body">
                        @if (session('status'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                {{ session('status') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif

                        <div>
                            Select the table you want to edit
                        </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="table_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Tables</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6" style="width: border-box">
                                    <SELECT id= "table_name" type="text" class="form-control @error('tables') is-invalid @enderror" name='table_name' style="width: 300px">


                                    
                                        <option> {{ $tables }}</option>


                                      

                                    </SELECT>
                                    @error('tables')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>


                    </div>
```

finally, this is thw web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\EditController::class, 'index']); // <-this is the controller
Route::get('/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'openEditBlade'])->name('edit');
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

Comment: in your route you have 2 same GET URI `edit` !!!

Comment: `undefined variable $test` , but you define `$tables`

Comment: sorry, lots of error of copy pasting, the error is on $tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have multiple Route::get() function with the same route. So, if you need to call any extra function in your controller, do that in controller.

```
Route::get('/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\EditController::class, 'index']);
```

In EditController.php

```
public function index() {
   // run the codes
   // call other function.
   $this->openEditBlade();
   // return view
   return view('edit')->with('tables',$tables);   
}
```

Comment: ok i the problem was that, i did not realized it was written twice